# Knockout validation - Config position (top or bottom) span error

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-validation

How do I configure the **span validation message** to be above or below the element?
Currently he is always created below the element.

**EDIT**

[Sample jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KHFn8/5826/)

**Steps:**

1. Click on the button
2. Inspect the first name input

See that span is below the input.

**HTML**:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="textInput: firstName">
<span class="validationMessage">This field is required.</span>
```

Is possible configure the position to span in the knockout validation plugin?

Comment: Your question is unlear. Can you provide example of your code? What is a span validation message, is it some kind of component - maybe you can provide a link?

Comment: @Olga, link provided.

Comment: great, I don't have much to add to Anish's answer - the documentation on the plugin says that `If you want to customize the display of your objects validation message, use the validationMessage binding` see link to docs https://github.com/ericmbarnard/Knockout-Validation

Answer (score 2):

You can use the *validationMessage* binding to supply your own markup and turn off the inserted messages.

```
<div class="row">
    <p class="validationMessage" data-bind="validationMessage: firstName"></p>
    <label>First name:</label>
    <input type="text" data-bind="textInput: firstName" />
</div>
<button type="button" data-bind='click: submit'>Click me</button>

ko.validation.init({
    registerExtenders: true,
    messagesOnModified: true,
    insertMessages: false,
    parseInputAttributes: true,
    messageTemplate: null
}, true);
```

Check the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KHFn8/5828/)

Comment: What's your scenario?

Answer (score 0):

**My temporary solution:**

Overriding InsertValidationMessage.

```
$ko.validation.insertValidationMessage = function (element) {
    var span = document.createElement('SPAN');
    span.className = "validationMessage";
    element.parentNode.insertBefore(span, element);
    return span;
};
```

[This functionality](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/issues/542) is already in the plans of the Knockout Validation team.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KHFn8/5836/)